# What kind of analysis to use to compare time series trade data

Tags: regression, time-series, intervention-analysis

I have a time series data set that gives me the adjusted imports and exports for the period 2003-2016. Suppose a trade agreement was signed in 2009. I want to compare the bilateral trade before and after the agreement, and check whether it increased bilateral trade.
How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to determine an agreement effect on trade between the two country. Wich can be studied by a binary variable (ex: periode) of the two different periode where you affect 1 for the periode 2003-2009, and 0 for 2009-2016.

Therefor try to compute a reg model :

Trade volume = periode  + all other variables you judg are determinante for trade between the two country.

Try to chose variables wich are very correlated to your periode variable, exemple : aspects wich related to economic crisis, because its happen on the same periode, ... this will reinforce estimation of the periode effect.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want to test whether a trade agreement had a statistically significant impact on bilateral trade. If that's the case then I would suggest testing for a structural break using a Chow Test (an econometric test)  considering you are analysing economic data. It is easy to implement and there's lots of information about it if you want to read further.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a real population as compared to a sample you do not need statistical test (some argue in fact you should not do them). Statistical test are designed to determine commonly if something in a sample is true of the unknown population. If you know the population as you do, then why do a statistical test? The decision if they matter (if there is a real process change) is a substantive decision not a statistical one. People confuse statistical significance with substantive significance in this manner. Having said that I know industrial engineers would likely disagree.:) They use statistical methods to determine if the process has changed (or to suggest that it has changed at least) and that is one approach you could try - if you disagree with my comments. You could look at the six sigma literature. But I am guessing you won't have enough data for that. Another option is segmented regression with a dummy variable that is set to 1 where you think the change occurred. Or simply use interrupted time series. A chow test is yet another option as mentioned.